# Redshift: Missing table in schema

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have couple of schema in the redshift DB, let's say **sch1** and **sch2** and have a table called **txn** that I can access as **sch1.txn and sch2.txn**

While in the process of identifying the data skew based on the query below from redshift doc(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/diagnostic-queries-for-query-tuning.html#identify-tables-with-data-skew-or-unsorted-rows), I couldn't find the table **txn** listed with **sch2** but only with **sch1**

```
SELECT trim(pgn.nspname) AS SCHEMA,
       trim(a.name) AS TABLE,
       id AS tableid,
       decode(pgc.reldiststyle,0, 'even',1,det.distkey,8,'all') AS distkey,
       dist_ratio.ratio::decimal(10,4) AS skew,
       det.head_sort AS "sortkey",
       det.n_sortkeys AS "#sks",
       b.mbytes,
       decode(b.mbytes,0,0,((b.mbytes/part.total::decimal)*100)::decimal(5,2)) AS pct_of_total,
       decode(det.max_enc,0,'n','y') AS enc,
       a.rows,
       decode(det.n_sortkeys, 0, NULL, a.unsorted_rows) AS unsorted_rows,
       decode(det.n_sortkeys, 0, NULL, decode(a.rows,0,0, (a.unsorted_rows::decimal(32)/a.rows)*100))::decimal(5,2) AS pct_unsorted
FROM
  (SELECT db_id,
          id,
          name,
          sum(ROWS) AS ROWS,
          sum(ROWS)-sum(sorted_rows) AS unsorted_rows
   FROM stv_tbl_perm a
   GROUP BY db_id,
            id,
            name) AS a
JOIN pg_class AS pgc ON pgc.oid = a.id
JOIN pg_namespace AS pgn ON pgn.oid = pgc.relnamespace
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT tbl,
          count(*) AS mbytes
   FROM stv_blocklist
   GROUP BY tbl) b ON a.id=b.tbl
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT attrelid,
          min(CASE attisdistkey
                  WHEN 't' THEN attname
                  ELSE NULL
              END) AS "distkey",
          min(CASE attsortkeyord
                  WHEN 1 THEN attname
                  ELSE NULL
              END) AS head_sort,
          max(attsortkeyord) AS n_sortkeys,
          max(attencodingtype) AS max_enc
   FROM pg_attribute
   GROUP BY 1) AS det ON det.attrelid = a.id
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT tbl,
          max(mbytes)::decimal(32)/min(mbytes) AS ratio
   FROM
     (SELECT tbl,
             trim(name) AS name,
             slice,
             count(*) AS mbytes
      FROM svv_diskusage
      GROUP BY tbl,
               name,
               slice)
   GROUP BY tbl,
            name) AS dist_ratio ON a.id = dist_ratio.tbl
JOIN
  (SELECT sum(capacity) AS total
   FROM stv_partitions
   WHERE part_begin=0 ) AS part ON 1=1
WHERE mbytes IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY mbytes DESC;
```

While debugging for the reason as shown below, I find that txn is listed only once which corresponds to **sch1**, but as I mentioned before I can access them both with sch1 and sch2. which is very very confusing.

Can someone help me understand, if this is somekind of permission issue with the schema, but I also find that based on ACL the user is entitled for both Usage & Create for the schema.

Is there way tables could be implicitly linked between schema???

```
rsdb=# SELECT db_id,
          id,
          name,
          sum(ROWS) AS ROWS,
          sum(ROWS)-sum(sorted_rows) AS unsorted_rows
   FROM stv_tbl_perm a where name = 'txn'
   GROUP BY db_id,
            id,
            name;
 db_id  |   id   |                                   name                                   |   rows   | unsorted_rows
--------+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+---------------
 100082 | 242000 | txn                                                                   | 65540000 |      65540000
```

Comment: Please do not tag Redshift questions with `postgresql` - they are very different

Comment: Can you run this and post the output?
`select schemaname, tablename from pg_table_def where schemaname in ('sch1', 'sch2') and tablename = 'txn';`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name resdhift runs on postgres and have a lot in common in terms of query lang, catalog management etc, so I guess there is nothing way off in tagging postgres for redshift question which does not deal with MPP

Comment: @JanZeiseweis (0 rows)

Comment: In this case your table doesn't exist in sch1 or sch2...

Comment: @JanZeiseweis When I do  select schemaname, tablename from pg_table_def where schemaname  = 'sch2' and tablename = 'txn'; I get (91 rows)

Comment: And when you let's say execute: `SELECT * FROM sch1.txn limit 1;` you don't get an error?
It could be, that **sch1.txn** or **sch2.txn** is a view and not a table.
try this: `select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.views where table_name = 'txn';`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154346/discussion-between-somasundaram-sekar-and-jan-zeiseweis).

Comment: Redshift is based an a **very**,  very old version of Postgres. They have deviated enough that the `postgresql` tag doesn't make sense for Redshift questions. The `sql` tag is enough for that